# How to tell Netbeans to treat a mustache file like a html file

Tags: netbeans

I am using Netbeans 12.2 and I am editing a file which its extension is `.mustache`.

Apparently, Netbeans doesn't recognize this file extension and there are none colors inside the editor. Is there a way, to tell Netbeans to handle this file like an html file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can associate a file extension with a mime type in Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Files.

To create a new extension, click on the "New" button:

[image]

Then select that extension and associate it with HTML files:

[image]